# Чем инициализируется %%i?

Tags: cmd

Начала изучать `cmd`, дошел переменной окружения `PATH` - смысл ее понятен, но вот что делает конструкция цикла, например, такого:

```
for %%i in ("%PATH:;=" "%") do (...something)
```

Не понимаю, чем инициализируется `i`? и как вообще понимать `in (...)` в этом случае?

Comment: Ну, это цикл по всем значения того, что в скобках.

Comment: кажется, разобрался: он последовательно выведет все пути, разделитель ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for %%i in (...)` интерпретируется очевидным образом - это цикл по набору значений, а вот как в данном случае строится набор значений - намного интереснее.

Запись `"%PATH:;=" "%"` интерпретируется следующим образом.

Всё, что между знаками `%` - это переменная и операторы её обработки. Операторы обработки начинаются после знака `:`. Т.е. в данном случае имя переменной - `PATH`, операторы обработки - `;=" "`. Поскольку в нашем выражении присутствует пробел, оно всё должно быть заключено в кавычки.

Оператор обработки в данном случае - это оператор замены. Строка слева от знака равенства будет замена на строку справа. Иными словами, конструкция

```
%VARIABLE:BEFORE=AFTER%
```

заменяет в переменной `VARIABLE` все вхождения строки `BEFORE` на строку `AFTER`. В нашем случае `;` - разделитель каталогов - будет заменена на пробел, который воспримет как разделитель элементов цикл `for`.

Answer (score 0):

Все ок: из переменной `PATH` последовательно будут взяты все возможные пути, разделитель ";"